# Add a js function to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I have a very simple HTML page. After everything is loaded, the user can interact with it perfectly. Now, at some point, the user clicks on an element. An ajax call is made and new data is being requested. I now want to remove the previous element the user clicked on with the element(s) the user has requested (on the same page) - practically remove the old element from the DOM and add the new one. Well, I did this as well, but I am unable to add a function to the newly created element. This is my function:

```
setCountry = function(value){
  document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = value;
}
```

and I'm trying to add it like this to my element

```
a_tag.setAttribute("href", "javascript:setCountry(countries[i]);");
```

The function is being called and writes "undefined" to the innerHTML element. I set the attribute using a for loop and just above the for loop I alert an element from the array to be sure it's correct, and it prints out the correct value.

I assume the problem happens because the function is being created on the first load of the DOM, but I'm not sure. Can anyone shed some light on what is really happening here and what I should do to correct it? I want to be able to add more functions so not looking for a work around writing an innerHTML tag, I just want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Edited with more code

```
//declare an array to hold all countries form the db
var countries = new Array();

function getCountries(region) {
    document.getElementById('scroller').innerHTML = '';

    //send the data to the server and retreive a list of all the countries based on the current region              
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/get_countries.php",
        data: {
            region: region
        },
        success: saveDataToArray,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    //save the data to an array
    function saveDataToArray(data){
        var i = 0;
        while (data[i]){
            countries[i] = data[i];
            i++;
        }                           
    }

    scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');

    //create a ul element
    var holder = document.createElement("ul");

    //here create a back button which will recreate the whole list of regions

    var total = countries.length;
    for(i=0;i<total;i++){

    //create the first field in the list
    var bullet_item = document.createElement("li");

    //create an a tag for the element
    var a_tag = document.createElement("a");

    //set the redirect of the tag 
    a_tag.setAttribute("href", "javascript:setCountry(this);");

    //create some text for the a_tag
    var bullet_text = document.createTextNode(countries[i]);

    //apend the text to the correct element
    a_tag.appendChild(bullet_text);

    //apend the a_tag to the li element
    bullet_item.appendChild(a_tag);

    //apend the item to the list
    holder.appendChild(bullet_item);                        
}

//apend the holder to the scroller
scroller.appendChild(holder);   
            }

function setRegion(region){
    document.getElementById('region').innerHTML = region;
}

setCountry = function(value){
    document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = value;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what `setCountry(countries[i]);` is. Is `i` a global variable?

Comment: We need more code. 1) How do you get `a_tag`? 2) Why do you use something that passes a string to be evaluated when I can almost certainly assume it won't be correctly?

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but you can't do that. Well you can, but that seems god awful, and would imply that `countries` and `i` are in the global state and that you hope to hook a call to `setCountry` as a handler to this `a` tag that you've somehow managed to select. You want to programmtically hook an event by using the event listener APIs at your disposal. Again, give more code and more details on what you actually want to do.

Comment: Added more code. Hopefully this will make it clearer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for quoting the code in a string. Instead of this:

```
a_tag.setAttribute("href", "javascript:...")
```

Try to form a closure:

```
a_tag.onclick = function () { ... }
```

Note that by default `<A>` elements without `HREF` do not look normal, but you can fix that with CSS.

Comment: sorry, tried it but still doesn't work. Somehow I don't have access to the countries array.

Comment: try again - in your code you certainly do have access to the global shared `countries` array, in the whole file. Whether `i` and `countries[i]` is defined or not is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
Everything was good apart from the way I was declaring the href parameter

```
a_tag.setAttribute("href", "javascript:setCountry("+'"'+countries[i]+'"'+")");
```

it's all the usual, a game of single quotes and double quotes.
Thanks everyone for pitching in ideas. Much appreciated as usual

Adrian

Comment: My 2c, for what it's worth, I consider this very poor style. Why not use a closure? It is simpler, executes faster, and does not break when your strings contain quotes or when you refactor your code and add a scope.

Comment: Mostly because I don't know what a closure is and why it is beneficial. However, you pointed out some interesting aspect that I should look into. As you've guessed, I'm very new to this so any help is much appreciated pointing me into the write direction. Thanks again. Pls fell free to add more observations. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the unnecessary terms. A closure is simply the function in this code: `a_tag.onclick = function () { .. }` - it is so called because it captures or "closes over" the free variables, in your case the `countries` array.